# Java syntax in argument

Tags: java

Can someone tell me what this strange syntax is ?   I tried to google it but could not get the correct hit.
        `Rating( movieName, rate: 5);`

It looks like some kind of json syntax.   what does "rate: 5" do ?   Thanks

[image]

Comment: Can you share a full snippet? This doesn't look like valid Java syntax.

Comment: It doesn't look like Java syntax to me.  Where did you find it?

Comment: Where have you seen this code? Can you post the URL where you copied that line?

Comment: This looks more like a feature of the IDE you are using to show the parameter names. Which IDE are you using?

Comment: The `rating:` that you see is not part of the code. It's a hint that is displayed by the IDE (IntelliJ in this case) to make the code easier to understand.

Comment: Oh, I see.  This was just a tutorial video that I saw.   I have never seen that syntax.  I thought it might be a new feature in java.   I would assume the actual syntax would be Rating( "5678", 3).   Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The real syntax, eventually parsed by the compiler, is:

```
new Rating("1234", 4);
```

The string you see preceding the parameter are just type hint from your IDE.